# chmod: WARNING: can't change .folder

Tags: shell, unix

I have only basic knowledge in Unix, that´s why I'm asking this.

I have the following problem.

Within my **home** directory:

```
/home/myName
```

I try to go to my folder "**.folder**"

```
 cd .folder/
```

and I get the following error:

> bash: cd: .folder/: Permission denied

The first thing that I tried logically was to give **777 permission**

I tried:

`chmod 777 .folder` or `chmod 0777 .folder`

> ```
> chmod: WARNING: can't change .folder
> ```

I do not know what else can I try

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on the [Unix & Linux stack exchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Try running `ls -la .folder` to see the permissions of that folder - it sounds like that isn't actually owned by you.

Comment: Hi @KaiJ sure, I got this: ls -la .folder/
.folder /:
 Permission denied total 0
 .folder/: Permission denied
total 0

Comment: @KaiJ: this is better: `ls -ltra | grep folder`, otherwise he'll try to get into that folder.

Comment: @Kaij using Dominique suggestions I got this ( I will add the info in a new comment line  below)

Comment: drwx------   2 myUserName  UIT.IT.UNIX_public_Group      96 Aug 20  2018 .folder

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are describing:

- your user does not own `.folder`, so you can't `chmod` it
- your user does not have execute permission for `.folder`, so you cannot `cd` into it

You can see who owns `.folder` by running this:

```
ls -la | grep ".folder"
```

From there, either change the permissions using `sudo` (if that's an option) – something like `sudo chmod ugo+rx .folder` – or contact the actual owner or admin for next steps.